# How can I find the most recent changeset in default to get merged into (other branch)?

Tags: mercurial, branch, branching-and-merging

It might be best to draw this out:

```
default -----A-----o-----o---->
              \
Branch_A  -----o-----o----->
                      \
Branch_B    -----o-----o-----o---->
                              \
Master                    -----o---->
```

Revision `A` is the "interesting" one here, as it's the most recent changeset in `default` to have been propagated into `Master`. How do I query Mercurial to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(As I was typing up this question, a co-worker put together the answer. I'll post anyway for anyone else using the Googles.)*

`hg log -r "max(ancestors(master) and branch(default))"`

This will return the most recent node in branch `default` that can trace a path into the `master` branch.